# Get the first cell from last row pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was able to get the last row of a DataFrame in pandas with this line

```
df.tail(1)
```

How do I get the first column's cell in this row? - I tried

```
df.tail(1)[0,0]
```

and it did not work

Comment: `df.iloc[-1,0]`????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this solution :

```
df.iloc[-1,0]
```

Read more about iloc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Comment: thank you!) the index cannot be applied to the dataframe generated by the tail() ?

Comment: @Dave you can do same with tail() output but it has extra overhead. Also the code will not be so clean.